# Changing Query Parameter for jQuery UI's Autocomplete

Tags: forms, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using version 1.8.13 of jQuery UI's Auto complete and by default jQuery is using the query parameter of "?term=" by default, while my app is using "?q=" in the string it is creating. I COULD change the variable to be "term" on the backend, but I'd rather just tell jQuery what the server is trying to send it. Is there a way to change this?

Right now I just have something like this and it works if I change the variable to "term" on the backend, but like I said I wanted to change it to "q" and I can't find any info online about setting the parameter (that works):

```
$( "#input-search").autocomplete({
   source: "/search/autocomplete/"
});
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use the [callback form of `source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) and handle all the interaction with the server yourself. Something like this:

```
$("#input-search").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.get('/search/autocomplete', { q: request.term }, function(data) {
            response(data.split('\n'));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: worth noting that you can actually change the search term using source too (I clean up email addresses with extra characters). The "search" method has already saved the search term, so changing the value there (in the input) is too late.

Answer (score 12):

The answer above is a great simple example and helped me get to this result on my app which generates an unordered list from the response data which displays the autocomplete results:

```
$("#input-search").autocomplete({
   source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
         url: "/search/autocomplete",
         dataType: "json",
         data: {
            q: request.term
         },
         success: function(data) {
            response(data);
         }
      });
   },
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    $(ul).attr('id', 'search-autocomplete');
       return $("<li class=\""+item.type+"\"></li>")
       .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
       .append("<a href=\""+item.url+"\">"+item.title+"</a>").appendTo(ul);
    };
```